# Algolia returning multiple results even when typoTolerance is set to false

Tags: algolia

I am currently facing an issue with Algolia search where it is returning multiple results even when typoTolerance is set to false in my search query. Specifically, when searching for **sales_admin@yopmail.com**, Algolia is returning the following results:

sales_admin@yopmail.com, sales_admin2@yopmail.com, salesadmin1@yopmail.com

I expect to see only the exact match of **sales_admin@yopmail.com** in the results.
Search is implemented on backend and the API internally sets typoTolerance to false and  searchableAttributes: ["firstName,lastName,email"],

Comment: are you sure you have set the typo tolerance to false. where/how do you set it. i tested with my index and gave only exact match